# Internet Explorer blocking

Tags: redirects, internet-explorer, code

How do I add a custom page that is displayed only to Internet Explorer users so that they are not able to access my blog.

I'm using Wordpress 3.3 and thought there would be a plugin for that or something but no luck (there's a plugin that only adds a pop up window).

Is that achieved by using some kind of redirect or what?

Comment: Do you really want to block IE users? You can't get your blog to work in IE at all?

Comment: This is not friendly to your blog visitors, why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) for IE users and then use JavaScript to redirect them to a page that tells them whatever it is you want to say.

Try something like this in the `<head>` of your web page:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = 'ie-only.html';
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I tried adding a code from the link you provided but don't understand how to use it really. Could you please add a sample code that would lead to page `mydomain.com/ie` whenever a user tries to access the website with IE? Also, where am I suppose to put the conditioning code? To `head`, before `head` or somewhere else?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example for you.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working, please check the [site](http://india.thefalljourney.com/). Thanks...

Comment: Sorry, made a typo. Try again.

Comment: I noticed that it redirects all the links that I click but not the home page. Also, it redirect links to `mydomain.com/[post-date]/[post-name]/ie-only.html` istead of `mydomain.com/ie-only`.

Comment: What you should do is either post this at stackoverflow or at the wordpress stackexchange site for further assistance as this is a separate issue from the original question and is now a coding question.